# Looping through table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm having problems looping through each entry in a table. Here is what Ive come up with thus far:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "td.sorting_1" ).each(function() {
var entry = $( this ).children( "a" );
var sitename = $( entry ).attr('href');
var sitenametest = sitename.lastIndexOf('/');
var ug = sitename.substring(sitenametest + 1)
var countTasks = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .task" ).length;
var countTasksOverdue = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskoverdue" ).length;
var countTasksDueToday = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskduetoday" ).length;
var countTasksDueTomorrow = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskduetomorrow" ).length;
$( entry ).closest("tr").append( "<td>" + countTasksOverdue + "</td><td>" + countTasksDueToday + "</td><td>" + countTasksDueTomorrow + "</td><td>" + countTasks + "</td>" );
$( "table#caseSummary thead tr" ).append( "<th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='OverdueTasks' style='width: 70px;'>Overdue Tasks</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TasksDueToday' style='width: 70px;'>Tasks Due Today</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TasksDueTomorrow' style='width: 70px;'>Tasks Due Tomorrow</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TotalTasks' style='width: 70px;'>Total Tasks</th>" );
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problems you're having? Are you running into an error? What do you expect your code to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sorry guys. Not good at explaining! I wanted it to find every td.sorting_1 and run that function below.

Comment: Not having a problem with my JS, but have no clue how to loop it for every TD.

Comment: it works fine, [here's the sample](https://jsfiddle.net/q5s2b1nm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function go()
    {
        var entries = $( "td.sorting_1 a" );
        var entryIndex = 0;

        $( "table#caseSummary thead tr" ).append( "<th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='OverdueTasks' style='width: 70px;'>Overdue Tasks</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TasksDueToday' style='width: 70px;'>Tasks Due Today</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TasksDueTomorrow' style='width: 70px;'>Tasks Due Tomorrow</th><th class='sorting' tabindex='0' aria-controls='caseSummary' rowspan='1' colspan='1' aria-label='TotalTasks' style='width: 70px;'>Total Tasks</th>" );
        for ( entryIndex = 0; entryIndex < entries.length; entryIndex++ )
        {
            addRow( entries[entryIndex] );
        }
    }


    function addRow( entry )
    {
        var sitename = $( entry ).attr('href');
        var sitenametest = sitename.lastIndexOf('/');
        var ug = sitename.substring(sitenametest + 1)
        var countTasks = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .task" ).length;
        var countTasksOverdue = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskoverdue" ).length;
        var countTasksDueToday = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskduetoday" ).length;
        var countTasksDueTomorrow = $( ".groupheader:contains('" + ug + "')" ).next( "ul.dfwp-list" ).find( "li.dfwp-item .taskduetomorrow" ).length;

        $( entry ).closest("tr").append( "<td>" + countTasksOverdue + "</td><td>" + countTasksDueToday + "</td><td>" + countTasksDueTomorrow + "</td><td>" + countTasks + "</td>" );
    }


    $( document ).ready( go ); 

</script>
```